# Supressing compiler error

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I use sbcl with slime.
I defined a function named `slot`, and sbcl compiler threw me an error following:

```
Lock on package SB-ALIEN violated when defining SLOT as a
function while in package COMMON-LISP-USER.
   [Condition of type SYMBOL-PACKAGE-LOCKED-ERROR]
See also:
  SBCL Manual, Package Locks [:node]

Restarts:
 0: [CONTINUE] Ignore the package lock.
 1: [IGNORE-ALL] Ignore all package locks in the context of this operation.
 2: [UNLOCK-PACKAGE] Unlock the package.
 3: [ABORT] Abort compilation.
 4: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 5: [ABORT] Abort thread (#<THREAD "worker" RUNNING {C3E4771}>)
```

It looks like the function name `slot` is reserved for some reason.
I can proceed with option 0 or 2, however, I don't want to see this error everytime after comilation.
Is it possible suppress this error after compilation?
I was thinking about not loading pre-reserved function name like slot, but I am not sure.

Comment: Your package is using the `SB-ALIEN` package, and it exports `SLOT`. Your code is trying to redefine that function, which could break that package.

Comment: If you don't use `SB-ALIEN:SLOT`, you could shadow it in your own package.

Comment: How do I "not use" SB-ALIEN package?

Comment: `SB-ALIEN` is used for the [foreign function interface](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Foreign-Function-Interface). If you're not calling C functions, I don't think you should need it.

Answer (score 4):

In the package you're working in, the name `slot` without a prefix is the same as the symbol `sb-alien:slot`. There are a number of ways to work around the fact that you can't use that name to name your own stuff (functions, macros, etc.)

First, you could construct your package in such a way that it doesn't use the `sb-alien` package. If you have `(:use sb-alien)` or similar in your `defpackage` form, you can take it out. After that, if you want to refer to an `sb-alien` symbol, you have to prefix it with `sb-alien:`. If there are only a few key symbols in `sb-alien` that you refer to all the time, you could use the `:import` clause to import them so you don't need the prefix.

Another option is to continue to `:use` the `sb-alien` package, but configure the package to exclude certain symbols. You could do this:

```
(defpackage #:my-great-package
  (:use #:cl #:sb-alien)
  (:shadow #:slot))
```

With a definition like that, `slot` without a prefix will refer to `my-great-package::slot`, but `define-alien-routine` without a prefix will refer to `sb-alien:define-alien-routine`.

There are lots of other options. The package system is pretty flexible in how it allows you to configure symbol references.